# select update query in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables, `#Table1` with columns `uniqueId`,`cpty_id`,`cpty_code` and `#Table2` with columns `cpty_id`,`cpty_code`,`unique_id`

now I want to update uniqueId of #Table1

like:

```
update #Table1 
set uniqueId = 
    (uniqeId from #Tabel2 
     where #Tabel2.cpty_id=#Table1.cpty_id 
       and #Table2.cpty_code=#Table1.cpty_code)
```

How this can be achived by update select query In oracle (I want to avoid loop)

Note: their is only one `uniqueId` for combination of `cpty_id` and `cpty_code` in both the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE 
  ( SELECT t1.uniqeId, 
           t2.uniqeId AS newUniqueId
    FROM 
        #Table1 t1
      JOIN 
        #Table2  t2
          ON  t2.cpty_id = t1.cpty_id 
          AND t2.cpty_code = t1.cpty_code
  ) tmp
SET 
    uniqueId = newUniqueId ;
```

or changing slightly your code (Warning! this will put **`NULL`** values in some rows in `table.uniqueId`, when there is no associated row in table 2):

```
update #Table1 
set uniqueId = 
    (SELECT #Table2.uniqeId from #Table2 
     where #Table2.cpty_id = #Table1.cpty_id 
       and #Table2.cpty_code = #Table1.cpty_code) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

please Try like the below

```
update #Table1 
set uniqueId = #Table2.uniqeId 
    (select <column_list> from #Tabel2) table2 
     where #Tabel2.cpty_id=#Table1.cpty_id 
       and #Table2.cpty_code=#Table1.cpty_code
```